# React Native Download JS Code from remote server

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-code-push, app-hub

I am currently doing an R&D in React Native.

I have a requirement where I need to add some modules(Basically code) in the app.

It is impossible in native iOS app to do so.

In React native apps using tools like [AppHub](https://apphub.io/) and [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/), we can push builds to production app.
There is a library [React Native Auto Updater](https://github.com/redbooth/react-native-auto-updater) for downloading latest js bundle but it is deprecated now.

Using the above tools, I need to push the build.

I have a scenario where I want the app to fetch and download the bundle kept on a remote server.

So, How can I download JS Code on making a rest API call from App and refresh the app as per the new JS code?

My concern is regarding download of JS Code.
I am clear on the Auto Update of apps part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think there is no library AFAIK i required the same for android and referred  Code Push Documents and for IOS u can try the same ,after downloading the bundle from the server you need to make sure the AppDelegate.m points to the resource file (Just a hint In android i created a fragment where the react native bundle is loaded ,once the bundle is downloaded i refresh the fragment  so that react native host  fetches the downloaded file).

Comment: I am looking for same I am new to this can you help me? how can I start to get basic idea ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eureka!

I accomplished this by doing the following:

1. Create an offline jsbundle Refer [this link](https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d)

   > react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
   >   index.android.js --bundle-output
   >   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
   >   android/app/src/main/res/
2. Create a Rest API for downloading js bundle. Refer [this link](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/032-return-file-from-spring-rest-webservice/)

   > I have used SpringBoot. Make sure you add this to your API **produces "text/javascript"**
3. Download the jsbundle in your app, store and get the path of the bundle.
4. Reset the path of bundle for React native in AppDelegate.m [for iOS] and in ReactApplication class [for Android]

Comment: Reset the path of bundle for React native in AppDelegate.m [for iOS] and in ReactApplication class [for Android]

Hi, what does this mean? I'm building on android and have issues figuring this out when you meant "ReactApplication class".

Comment: @Han ReactApplication class means the class which is extending Application and implementing ReactApplication

Comment: Thanks, after a was able to make it working as well. :)

Comment: What will happen if offline js bundle is using a third party library which is not included in my main app.

Answer (score 3):

Try the **react-native-dynamic-bundle** package: https://github.com/mauritsd/react-native-dynamic-bundle

Also, you can download the bundle using **react-native-fs**:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'

export const download = async (fromUrl, bundleName) => {
  return RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl,
    toFile: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + `/${bundleName}.bundle`,
  }).promise
}
```

Regards, Juan

Comment: Hi Juan, I am able to download the bundle using react-native-fs but registerBundle (react-native-dynamic-bundle) with the path of dowloaded bundle fails with below error:
"TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNDynamicBundle.registerBundle')". How did you get this working?